# Does there exist a nontrivial Lie group morphism $\Phi: S^1 \to \mathbb R$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-homomorphism

Consider $(\mathbb R, +)$ and $S^1 := \mathbb R / 2 \pi \mathbb Z$.
Both of these Lie groups have Lie algebra $(\mathbb R, [\cdot,\cdot] = 0)$. 
Does there exists a Lie group morphism $\Phi: S^1 \to \mathbb R$ such that $(\Phi_*)_e = \text{id}_{\mathbb R}$, where $e$ denotes the identity element of $S^1$?

My idea is the following.
As $\Phi: S^1 \to \mathbb R$ is a Lie group morphism, it is continuous.
Hence, as $S^1$ is connected and compact, its image is a bounded, closed interval of $\mathbb R$. However, the only subgroup of $(\mathbb R, +)$ that is of the form of a bounded, closed interval is the trivial group, i.e. $[0, 0] = \{0\}$. Therefore, $\Phi \equiv 0$, so $(\Phi_*)_e \equiv 0$, which proves that there doesn't exist such a $\Phi$.
Is it really that simple?

Comment: Yes, it is. What are your doubts?